# Why does my Label not have a textAlign property?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, label

I create a spark.components.Label, and I want to change the text alignment. The [api](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html) states it has a property textAlign, but I get this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
import spark.components.Label;
var mylabel:Label = new Label();
mylabel.textAlign = "right";
```

> Error: Access of possibly undefined property textAlign through a
>   reference with static type spark.components:Label.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API states that Label has a **style** called `textAlign`, not a property.

If you wish to assign a style through ActionScript, you can do so like this:

```
myLabel.setStyle('textAlign', 'right');
```

See [IStyleClient#setStyle](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/styles/IStyleClient.html#setStyle%28%29)